# How to make a Row take the full width of it's parent in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create this peace of UI

[image]

The problem is in the **Red Row** that contains the ***Title*** and the ***Date***. I want this **Row** to take the full width of it' parent widget so I can add a space between these two **Text** widgets...and that is what I'v done so far.

```
Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1, color: AppColors.tertiary),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(240),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(image, width: 48, height: 48),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 6),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          title,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          date,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.copyWith(color: AppColors.tertiary),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 3),
                  Text(
                    value.toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.copyWith(color: AppColors.tertiary),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I tried to wrap this **Row** with a **Extended** widget and and a **SizedBox.expand()** but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need wrap your `Container` that contain Column with `Expanded` widget:

```
Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(240),
        ),
        child: Image.asset(image, width: 48, height: 48),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 6),
      Expanded( //<---- add this
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Column(
```

Comment: Hey, when I do this, the column inside my row seems to take up the whole vertical space (it stretches the row to take all of the available space). Any idea how i can restrict it to the minimum possible space within the row ?

Comment: can you add your full code to see what widget do you have in your widget tree?

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.black12),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(240),
          ),
          child: Text('image'),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 6),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'title',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.copyWith(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'date',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .bodyText2
                            ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black12),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 3),
                Text(
                  'value',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .bodyText2
                      ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black12),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

You have to wrap the Container that has that Row as a child with an Expanded widget in order to let him know that you want it to take all the available space.

NOTE: Take into account that I've made some changes to your variables/colors in order to test it on Flutter pad!

Comment: Thank you...appreciate your effort.